# what image extensions are allowed in MIME type image

Tags: javascript, mime-types

If this is the wrong place for this type of question i apologise, what i want to know is what image extensions does /image.*/ encompas, and how do you include multiple different ones like /application.*/ and /image.*/ can you even combine them ?

also is there a list somewhere where you can see all accepted extensions ?

Comment: Do you mean in a `file` input element?

Comment: _"can you even combine them ?"_ - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a file input you can set the accept attribute to a comma separated list of file extensions (e.g. `.jpg`, dot included) or MIME types, including wildcards. e.g.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>
```

As far as a mime type list goes, they are governed by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).